# Disable TypeScript from checking types validity when building for production

Tags: typescript, next.js

I am using using Next.js with TypeScript for a small project. I am wondering if it's possible to disable types validity checks when I run `npm run build` considering type checking happened during `npm run dev`. Plus this will help to build production build without TypeScript package which is not used in production.

Comment: You're not running TS directly anywhere as there's no engine that runs it. TS is transpiled/compiled to JS when it's running anywhere. So if you're not getting any TS error running in dev mode, you don't have to worry about it with build. But if you're getting TS errors but still wants to do prod build, you can follow the answer by @boundevid.

Comment: The issue i am facing is that when running ```npm run build``` type checking is taking rather long time. Considering that type checking already happened when i run ```npm run dev``` I would prefer to disable when running for production

Comment: When you run `npm run build`, it's actually doing a lot more than just type checking. It's doing lots of things to make sure resulting JS (not TS) file is optimized for the production. And it has no relation to `npm run dev` state. You have to understand that TypeScript is a dev time environment, not run time environment. When it's running on the browser or node, it's actually running compiled JS. No type checking is happening at all.

Comment: Thats interesting. I was not aware that there's more to type checking. I guess I will have to let it be . Thanks

Comment: I don't think you understood me correctly. TS type checking is done by the language server for your IDE when you're running in dev. TS type checking is done by the compiler when you're building. What's being done more when you build is plain JS + CSS packing stuff. This is same process used by any kind of JS stack. But yeah, in the end, it is what it is unless you're trying to understand the whole process and customize to your need.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Open `next.config.js` and enable the `ignoreBuildErrors` option in the typescript config:

```js
module.exports = {
  typescript: {
    // !! WARN !!
    // Dangerously allow production builds to successfully complete even if
    // your project has type errors.
    // !! WARN !!
    ignoreBuildErrors: true,
  },
}
```

More info on the docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/ignoring-typescript-errors

Comment: Dangerous but I need it for now! cheers